# Using ArcScripts that are AML from ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, references, terrain, aml

I use ArcGIS 10
I want to use an arcscript to compute an index of ruggedness for each cell of my map. For this  purpose, I found, Evan's TRI.aml script here:
http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12435

I have never added a script to  ArcGIS before. So I downloaded it, and aded to as a script to my newly created toolbox. 
However, I do not know what to enter when I am asked to add parameters, and if I don't add any  I cannot use the script when I double click on it.

No specific indication on "parameters" is available on the website from which I downloaded the aml file.

Comment: Do you have ArcInfo Workstation installed?

Comment: You might look at this: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/31400-Python-quot-Ruggedness-quot-Analysis-Code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ArcInfo Macro Language (AML)** is old in ESRI Terms though it is possible to run .amls in ArcGIS 10.0
if you have the right requirements:

*It's possible to use ARC Macro Language (AML) files in the ArcGIS Desktop environment by creating a new geoprocessing script tool. If you have an ArcInfo license and ArcInfo Workstation installed, you can add a custom script tool that references an AML.*

**Though the recommendation is to convert it to Python**

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000012000000.htm

**Using AML with script tools** (ArcGIS 10.0 with Workstation installed)
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000010000000.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I'm just gonna go for converting the script to Python

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a Tool to run the AML. If you have ArcInfo installed follow these steps.
copy the aml to that same folder as your DEM
open a cmd window
cd to the folder where your DEM is located
enter arc
enter &r tri.aml yourdem outputdem

Comment: For clarification sake, you actually need to have ArcInfo ***WORKSTATION*** installed.  This is different than an ArcGIS (ArcMap) ArcInfo license.